# Why is WordPress caching values from get_option() when you're on the front-end of the site, but not the dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, plugins

I've developed a WordPress plugin that should make things like pop-ups easy for non-programmers to operate and use, but I've come across one particular issue that I can't track the source of.  I created an extensive options page through which a user can go in and change multiple settings related to the pop-up, save them, and then see the changes instantly on the front-end of the website.  However, I've noticed that it takes at least a few minutes for those changes to take hold for some reason.

Upon further investigation I tried grabbing a lot of these options using get_option('insert_key_here') and then printing them out at the start of the plugin's code to see what was going on.  If I'm on the dashboard of the website, it's fine, all the options print out as they should be, even if I had just changed them through the options page.  But if I then go to the front-end of the website, the same printouts will show the old options for anywhere between 5 - 15 minutes.

None of this seems to make any sense as, to my knowledge, there is no caching on the site I am working with.  W3 Total Cache is shut off, any other external caching is off, browser cache shouldn't be an issue since this is all server-side, and no caching that I know off would differentiate between whether you're looking at a site's home page or its WordPress dashboard.

Unfortunately I'm pretty sure I can't show the exact code due to copyright reasons and the fact that it's very long to begin with, but I was hoping someone may know why such a strange bug would happen, or maybe give me some advice on what to look for that could lead to an answer.

TL;DR

- The options are being saved immediately by the options page because the printout of the options reflects these changes on the WordPress dashboard
- However those same options are not being immediately updated on the front-end of the website
- Caching appears to not be an issue because W3 is off, external caches are off, browser cache should not play a factor because this is all dealing with PHP (server-side), and no cache (that I know of) should be selectively caching the front-end of the website.
- I know this is a bit nebulous and there isn't much to go on, but maybe someone can offer advice on what to look for?

Comment: Have you tested this on a separate (maybe local) server, where you have full control of the server environment? I'm just asking because hosts like wp-engine cache things automatically for you, and wordpress also has a built in cache system.

Comment: @rmmoul I have not, and it would be very difficult for me to do so because this is very much related to my job, hence why I'm a bit light on the details and not showing any code.  Even if it wasn't related, I don't have the space nor server management know-how to try and copy it all to an environment that I could have tighter control over.  I could maybe write up some pseudo-code to give an idea of how I'm saving the plugin settings and how I'm testing them, maybe give a better idea of what's happening, and where/when it's happening.

Comment: Pseudo code couldn't hurt, but short of your code using the wordpress caching functions, I can't think of anything other than process of elimination style testing (change server environments, check from multiple browsers/computers, write barebones test code to save an option and pull it on the front-end to see if it gets cached too, etc.).

Comment: @rmmoul I managed to find two different solutions to my issue, though both are less than desirable.  The first is to replace 'get_option()' with direct queries of the database using $wpdb and finding the meta value I want.  The other is a function 'wp_cache_flush()' that resets the built-in cache of 'get_option()', but I believe it flushes ALL cache, not just the ones I want, so it could lead to undesirable effects.  In the end, I'm just going to live with the inherent delay the plugin has for now unless it becomes a bigger problem in the future.

Comment: try crtl + f5 when you make changes. The caching plugin only caches front end pages and not admin and when removed dosen't remove cleanly as far as i remember. Thats the most likely cause. WP settings also has query caching in its settings..you can turn it on/off.